# error Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property. ChildScope

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid

This is an ionic app, I have no idea why I am getting the error below when I start my application. I didn't notice when it started to popup and now I cannot get rid of it. Any suggestions clues of how I could debug and find this issue?

```
 896167   error    Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
ChildScope@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21459:42
$new@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21467:40
boundTranscludeFn@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14901:40
controllersBoundTransclude@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:15558:35
ngIfWatchAction@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:31241:26
$digest@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22020:31
$apply@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22282:31
done@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17439:53
completeRequest@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17629:15
requestLoaded@http://192.168.1.106:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17570:24
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My first guess ist to debug into the ionic.bundle.js (non minified version) and try to get the name of that read only property. Without it it's next to impossible to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error went away all together with the latest Ionic update, 1.0.0-rc.5 "tungsten-turkey"